# Change routing priority on iMac

Tags: network, high-sierra, imac

Our home phone/internet is down; dug up by council contractors, and won't be fixed for a week.
I am using an iPhone hotspot in the interim.

This works, but when I plug the Ethernet connection to my router into my iMac I can no longer access the internet.
I use the local network for file sharing and printing.

How can I stop the iMac from using the Ethernet connection for internet, or PREFERABLY set the priority for the hotspot to be higher when connected?

172.20.10.1 is the Hotspot IP

```
~$ netstat -nr
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            10.1.1.1           UGSc           53        0     en0
default            172.20.10.1        UGScI          13        0     en1
10.1.1/24          link#6             UCS             2        0     en0
10.1.1.1/32        link#6             UCS             1        0     en0
10.1.1.1           78:a0:51:16:bb:56  UHLWIir        31      156     en0   1192
10.1.1.9/32        link#6             UCS             2        0     en0
10.1.1.255         ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        1     en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              1      300     lo0
169.254            link#6             UCS             0        0     en0
169.254            link#7             UCSI            0        0     en1
172.20.10/28       link#7             UCS             1        0     en1
172.20.10.1/32     link#7             UCS             1        0     en1
172.20.10.1        3e:2e:f9:2a:33:64  UHLWIir        15       12     en1   1181
172.20.10.5/32     link#7             UCS             0        0     en1
172.20.10.15       ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        1     en1
224.0.0/4          link#6             UmCS            2        0     en0
224.0.0/4          link#7             UmCSI           2        0     en1
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI          0        0     en0
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI          0        0     en1
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI          0       10     en0
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI          0       10     en1
255.255.255.255/32 link#6             UCS             1        0     en0
255.255.255.255    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        2     en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#7             UCSI            0        0     en1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Researching this I was able to find this SU Q&A titled: [How does Mac OSX prioritize network interfaces when routing?](https://superuser.com/questions/472454/how-does-mac-osx-prioritize-network-interfaces-when-routing) which shows a method to do what you want. This Q&A mentions that macOS orders routing based on the ordering on the network interfaces.

#### Device ordering

You can see this order with this command:

```
$ networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder
An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled.
(1) Wi-Fi
(Hardware Port: Wi-Fi, Device: en0)

(2) Bluetooth PAN
(Hardware Port: Bluetooth PAN, Device: en6)

(3) Thunderbolt Bridge
(Hardware Port: Thunderbolt Bridge, Device: bridge0)
```

So routes associated with the device `en0` (Wi-Fi) will have a higher precedence than routes associated with the device `bridge0` (Thunderbolt Bridge). You can use this command to reorder these:

```
$ networksetup -ordernetworkservices "Thunderbolt Bridge" "Bluetooth PAN" "Wi-Fi"
```

Now the order is like this:

```
$ networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder
An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled.
(1) Thunderbolt Bridge
(Hardware Port: Thunderbolt Bridge, Device: bridge0)

(2) Bluetooth PAN
(Hardware Port: Bluetooth PAN, Device: en6)

(3) Wi-Fi
(Hardware Port: Wi-Fi, Device: en0)
```

#### Your setup

For you you'll want to reorder your devices so that the routes from your tethered device, `en1` are order higher than your routes from `en0`.

*Before*

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            10.1.1.1           UGSc           53        0     en0
default            172.20.10.1        UGScI          13        0     en1
```

*After*

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            172.20.10.1        UGScI          13        0     en1
default            10.1.1.1           UGSc           53        0     en0
```

Comment: The iMac insisted I list all 9 services! `networksetup -ordernetworkservices "Wi-Fi" "Ethernet" "iPhone USB" "iPad USB" "FT232R USB UART" "Bluetooth PAN" "Thunderbolt Bridge" "Thunderbolt Bridge 2" "Bluetooth DUN"` - most of these are unknown, and a hangover from my 1st 3G phone. I can't seem to remove them either.

Comment: @Milliways - sounds like another Q to ask here 8-)

Comment: @Milliways - I think you can get rid of them lie this - `sudo ifconfig <device> down`

Answer (score 3):

You can set the service order in the *Network* preference pane in Preferences.app.

Open *Network* preferences, click the small cogwheel icon below network connection list (next to the + and – icon), choose "Set Service Order…" in the menu.

Then you just drag the entries in the dialog (w/o typing all the interface names).

Btw., in the Network pref pane you can also delete unused network interfaces (– icon) or make them inactive (cogwheel menu).

[image: macOS Network pref pane]