# How can I easily add and delete routing to an IP address for testing?

Tags: network

My LAN uses 172.16.7.xxx. Both my DHCP server and gateway are at 172.16.7.1. (It's a firewall box.) On the other side of that firewall is my cellular broadband modem with an address of 192.168.1.1 and it has a DHCP server that assigns an address in the 192.168.1.xxx range to the WAN interface on my firewall.

I've just received and set up my dish for Starlink internet. It has a single device that provides PoE for the dish and acts as a firewall and wifi router. It does not have an ethernet connection until I get my ethernet adaptor, which is backordered. I have about 1,000 feet of fiber optic cable between my LAN "heart" (patch panel, switch, firewall, servers - all on a few shelves in one closet). So until the ethernet adaptor arrives, the only way I can connect to the Starlink equipment is by wifi. (The post the dish is mounted on has a climate controlled box where the Starlink hub goes.)

I've put a Raspberry Pi in the box on that post. The Pi's ethernet interface (eth0) is on my home LAN at 172.16.7.6. When I ssh into the Pi, I can confirm the wifi interface (wlan0) has been given an IP address by the Starlink router. (The Starlink router also uses the 192.168.1.xxx space.)

My main workstation is my iMac. I want to be able to test the bridge I've created (from a SE:Superuser post) and test the connection to the internet using that Pi as a wifi bridge.

How can I easily add or change my routing to go through 172.16.7.6 instead of 172.16.1 (and still use that as the address for the DHCP server) and then, when I'm done testing, easily change back to my normal routing?

Eventually, when the adaptor comes in, I'll be using that on the other side of my normal firewall, but for now I want to be able to test my Starlink connection and, in case there are issues, quickly and easily switch back to my normal routing.

(I considered putting the Pi on the other side of my firewall, but that doesn't work because it could knock everything else off if something is wrong with the connection. Also, my iMac is upstairs and the LAN switch is downstairs, so I don't want to have to go back and forth for testing.)

Comment: route add/route delete . Also you can switch off cellular modem to see if you can go through starling as both routing will go to internet.

Comment: @PtitXav The cell modem is also downstairs. For a "final" test I don't mind changing things over or going up and down the stairs, but until I'm sure the bridge works, I want to make the changes only on my iMac. That way it's easy to switch back and forth without messing up any other systems. I figured I could test with traceroute until I know it's working.

Comment: May be [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356744/change-routing-priority-on-imac) will give you some clue. It talks about routing priorities.